# Powershell Windows Form listbox selection validation

Tags: winforms, powershell, listbox, error-checking

I have created a powershell script using windows forms containing list boxes to run a cmd command (helps eliminate user-error and expedites process a bit).  The only problem I run into is the command will still attempt to run even if an item is not selected on one of the forms I have populate.  This can cause the script to simply not run, or it can cause mass amounts of data to be downloaded (the script pulls log files from a server, the listbox helps narrow down the data to be pulled).  Is there a way to create error checking for the listbox that will essentially say "hey, you didn't select anything!" before continuing?
Thanks!

Edit (example of first list box):

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$form.Text = "Select a production environment"
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(190,250) 
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,180)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
$form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
$form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(85,180)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
$form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
$form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
$label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$label.Text = "Please select a production environment:"
$form.Controls.Add($label) 

$listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
$listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20) 
$listBox.Height = 140

[void] $listBox.Items.Add("server1")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("server2")
[void] $listBox.Items.Add("server3")


$form.Controls.Add($listBox) 

$form.Topmost = $True

$result = $form.ShowDialog()

if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $Prod = $listBox.SelectedItem
    $Prod
}
```

Comment: Please provide [MCVE].

Comment: Added listbox example.  If you need more, let me know.  This is the first form of three.  First two are listboxes, third is text input from the user (the actual search term).  If the user doesn't select a server from this list, the script uses it as a wildcard, which returns WAY too much data.  I would like a validation/error-check that says "select a thing" if they try to click "ok" before selecting one.

Comment: You can check `$listBox.SelectedIndex -gt -1` to make sure an item is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way to perform this kind of validation using Windows Forms methods, but this uses PowerShell.

---

Perform `$result = $form.ShowDialog()` in a `Do..Until` or `Do..While` loop and continue showing the dialogue until the user has selected at least one item, and pressed `OK` - or the user exits the dialogue - else, show a warning and show the dialogue again.
Here is the relevant PowerShell code:

```
do
{
    $result = $form.ShowDialog()

    if ($ListBox.SelectedIndices.Count -lt 1 -and $result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {
        Write-Warning 'Nothing was selected, please select a server.'
    }
}
until (($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK -and $listBox.SelectedIndices.Count -ge 1) -or $result -ne [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
```

Of course, you can replace `Write-Warning` with whatever you want, such as a message box.

---

PS: You can use the `AddRange` method to add an array of items to the `$listBox` collection, like so: `[void] $listBox.Items.AddRange(@("server1", "server2", "server3"))`

Comment: Will test this today!  Thank you very much for your help!